# Develop app just to showcase a website on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, emulation, collaboration

So what I want to do is, "develop" an app where it main purpose is just to open a website. I need that on android and ios. Is there an online website to do just that?

I jused to know a website, where you could develop for various platforms (PHP, Java, Object C for iOs) and even test your code online.

Somehow I can't find it anywhere. Thank in advance if you can either show me the website again or find me a new website to do just that.

Regards!

Update:
Found the website: http://www.programmr.com/

Comment: Apple will reject any such app. Don't bother wasting your time developing this for iOS.

Comment: it is for a client and he just wants that, showcase his website through an app

Comment: Tell your client that Apple doesn't accept apps that are simply wrappers to a website. See the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#user-interface). Specifically 2.12. - "Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected".

Comment: thank you but i am still on the lookout for that website where i can just code online and test it as well :-(

Comment: btw found the website: http://www.programmr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referencing [PhoneGap.](https://build.phonegap.com/)

PhoneGap allows you to build native applications using HTML/CSS/JS for all mobile operating systems.

Comment: no, it was without downloading anything. it was purely a website

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is for your iPhone App and Android App to open up a website "inside" of the application, you will want to use a webView. This will allow you to have your application listed on the iOS App Marketplace and the Android Google Play Store.

EDIT: This will definitely work on Android. You must get pass Apples app approval process to get on iOS of course.

Comment: how do i do that, is there a website which lets me do just that?